# how to override downloader directory with local directory in polyglot in python

Tags: python, server, nlp, polyglot

I run polyglot sentiment detection. When I upload it to the server I cannot run the `downloader.download("TASK:sentiment2")` command, so I downloaded the sentiment2 folder and saved it in the same folder as the python file.

I tried to set `downloader.download_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'polyglot_data')` pointing at the sentiment2 folder location as it says in the [polyglot documentation](https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/polyglot.html#module-polyglot.downloader) but it doesnt work.

**How do I override downloader directory so it will access the sentiment2 local folder when it executes the sentiment analysis?**

Please see the full code below. This code works on my computer and localhost but returns zero when I run it on the server.

```
from polyglot.downloader import downloader
#downloader.download("TASK:sentiment2")
from polyglot.text import Text

downloader.download_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'polyglot_data')

def get_text_sentiment(text):
   result = 0
   ttext = Text(text)
   for w in ttext.words:
      try:
         result += w.polarity
      except ValueError:
         pass
   if result: 
      return result/ len(ttext.words)
   else:
      return 0

text = "he is feeling proud with ❤"
print(get_text_sentiment(text))
```

my localhost returns - 0.1666

the server returns - 0.0

Answer (score 0):

after looking at the polyglot git [init](https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/blob/master/polyglot/__init__.py) function. Its an env. issue. `data_path = os.environ.get('POLYGLOT_DATA_PATH', data_path)`

So I removed the  `downloader.download_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'polyglot_data')`
and simply define the local POLYGLOT_DATA_PATH in the env. path.
It worked.